# react-redux ssr async api call not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to implement server side rendering for my react App. I am using redux, thunk also.

when i am trying to dispatch action to call API for that page. I want to wait for api call to finish and then render html at server and send that. But my promise got resolved before i get response from api.

Here is my code.

```
const promises = [];
  routes.map(({ route, match }) => {
    if (route && route.loadData) {
      const loadRes = route.loadData(store, match);
      console.log('l', loadRes);
      promises.push(loadRes);
    }
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .catch(() => promises)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('caall');
      render(req, res, store);
    });
```

my routes

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
    exact: true,
    loadData: (dispatch) => dispatch(getNews(0)),
  },
  {
    path: '/:pageNumber/page',
    component: Home,
    loadData: (store, match) => {
      return [store.dispatch(getNews(match.params.pageNumber))];
    },
  },
];
```

this is my action

```
export const getNews = (page) => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?page=${page || 0}`
  );
  const res = await getHits(response.data);
  console.log('hit', res.length);

  dispatch({ type: 'UpdateNews', payload: res });
};
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong. I am response after i render html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `loadData` function in `/:pageNumber/page` route returns array of promises instead of promise. So when you pass nested array into `Promise.all()` function it resolves instantly.
2. You have incorrect `loadData` function signature in `/` route, because you pass store as a first argument, not dispatch.

That said, you should modify your routes code as follows:

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
    exact: true,
    loadData: ({ dispatch }) => dispatch(getNews(0)),
  },
  {
    path: '/:pageNumber/page',
    component: Home,
    loadData: (store, match) => {
      return store.dispatch(getNews(match.params.pageNumber));
    },
  },
];
```